# Converting from $http to $resource in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var customersApp = angular.module('customersApp', ['ngGrid']);
var url = 'api/Customer';

//the factory object for the webAPI call.
customersApp.factory('customerRepository', function ($http) {
    return {
        insertUser: function (callback,user) {
            var user = { "id": user.id, "city": user.city, "name": user.name, "address": user.address, "contactNo": user.contactNo, "emailId": user.emailId };
            $http.post(url, user).success(callback);
        }

});
```

Controller is

```
customersApp.controller('customerCtrl', function ($scope, customerRepository) {
        customerRepository.insertUser(function () {
                alert('customer inserted successfully');
            }, $scope.New)
    });
```

What I am trying to do is change the $http to $resource on the factory like this

```
customersApp.factory('customerRepository', function($resource){
return
 $resource(url, { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'POST', } })
}
```

My question is when I am changing from $http to $resource where do I put the "user" data that was in factory insertUser being used.

Please let me know in $resource in factory where do i insert the "user" data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

**The resource factory creates the object and uses object instance data as POST**

```
customersApp.factory("customerRepository", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://someUrl", {}, {
        update: {method : "POST"}
    });
});
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.data = {}; // your data initialization stuff
$scope.data.someDataKey = 'someDataValue'; // add your default data

var customerrepository = new customerRepository($scope.data);
customerrepository.$update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
customersApp.controller('customerCtrl', function ($scope, $resource) {
    var customerRepository = $resource(url)
    customerRepository.save($scope.New, function () {
            alert('customer inserted successfully');
        })
});
```

This is using $resouce's default resource action `save`, and the definition is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

```
non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
```

If using instance action, the post data is passed in when creating the resource by using `new`